# My loss starts increasing as I decay learning rate, Tensorflow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm using exponential decay to decay my learning rate after every 10 epochs. As you can see in the output below, as my learning rate starts to decrease, my loss starts to increase and I've tried several variations and same thing happens every time. What could go wrong?

```
 global_step = tf.Variable(0, name="global_step", trainable=False)
 decayed_learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(learning_rate = 0.0001,global_step = global_step,decay_steps = 1000, decay_rate = 0.6, staircase = True)
 optimizer= tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate = decayed_learning_rate, momentum = 0.9)
 minimize_loss = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
```

Here is the output:

```
 1
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 8.291080, Training Accuracy= 0.18000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 8.464677, Validation Accuracy= 0.10000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 8.631430, Test Accuracy= 0.13000
    2
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 4.619487, Training Accuracy= 0.12000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 4.835144, Validation Accuracy= 0.14000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 5.233496, Test Accuracy= 0.09000
    3
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 4.591153, Training Accuracy= 0.10000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 4.878084, Validation Accuracy= 0.09000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 4.112285, Test Accuracy= 0.11000
    4
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 4.530641, Training Accuracy= 0.13000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 4.874103, Validation Accuracy= 0.10000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 4.225502, Test Accuracy= 0.14000
    5
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 3.664831, Training Accuracy= 0.26000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 3.207108, Validation Accuracy= 0.29000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 4.435939, Test Accuracy= 0.17000
    6
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 3.682740, Training Accuracy= 0.26000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 3.794605, Validation Accuracy= 0.21000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 3.890673, Test Accuracy= 0.17000
    7
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 3.638363, Training Accuracy= 0.27000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 4.057161, Validation Accuracy= 0.21000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 4.400304, Test Accuracy= 0.19000
    8
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 3.290856, Training Accuracy= 0.13000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 3.573865, Validation Accuracy= 0.02000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 3.289892, Test Accuracy= 0.13000
    9
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 3.249848, Training Accuracy= 0.13000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 3.816904, Validation Accuracy= 0.09000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 3.365518, Test Accuracy= 0.09000
    10
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 3.261417, Training Accuracy= 0.13000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 3.051553, Validation Accuracy= 0.13000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 3.935049, Test Accuracy= 0.10000
    11
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 3.274293, Training Accuracy= 0.12000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 3.341079, Validation Accuracy= 0.12000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 3.465601, Test Accuracy= 0.09000
    12
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 3.245074, Training Accuracy= 0.12000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 3.655849, Validation Accuracy= 0.09000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 3.890745, Test Accuracy= 0.11000
    13
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 3.242341, Training Accuracy= 0.12000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 3.527991, Validation Accuracy= 0.04000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 3.207819, Test Accuracy= 0.12000
    14
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 3.277830, Training Accuracy= 0.12000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 3.797029, Validation Accuracy= 0.10000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 3.317770, Test Accuracy= 0.11000
    15
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 3.269509, Training Accuracy= 0.12000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 3.074466, Validation Accuracy= 0.12000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 3.887167, Test Accuracy= 0.10000
    16
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 4.100363, Training Accuracy= 0.14000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 4.208894, Validation Accuracy= 0.10000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 4.150678, Test Accuracy= 0.15000
    17
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 4.037428, Training Accuracy= 0.14000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 4.366947, Validation Accuracy= 0.10000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 4.501517, Test Accuracy= 0.09000
    18
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 4.048151, Training Accuracy= 0.14000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 4.315053, Validation Accuracy= 0.10000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 3.972508, Test Accuracy= 0.10000
    19
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 4.046428, Training Accuracy= 0.14000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 4.649216, Validation Accuracy= 0.08000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 4.125694, Test Accuracy= 0.11000
    20
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 4.082591, Training Accuracy= 0.13000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 3.639134, Validation Accuracy= 0.16000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 4.476624, Test Accuracy= 0.16000
    21
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 4.068653, Training Accuracy= 0.13000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 4.141028, Validation Accuracy= 0.10000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 4.086758, Test Accuracy= 0.15000
    22
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 4.066084, Training Accuracy= 0.13000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 4.252730, Validation Accuracy= 0.10000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 4.357038, Test Accuracy= 0.10000
    23
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 4.031103, Training Accuracy= 0.14000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 4.360917, Validation Accuracy= 0.10000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 3.916987, Test Accuracy= 0.11000
    24
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 4.031075, Training Accuracy= 0.14000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 4.653004, Validation Accuracy= 0.07000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 4.183711, Test Accuracy= 0.10000
    25
    Epoch Finished
    Loss after one Epoch(Training) = 4.039016, Training Accuracy= 0.14000
    Loss after one Epoch(Validation) = 3.654388, Validation Accuracy= 0.15000
    Loss after one Epoch(Test) = 4.228384, Test Accuracy= 0.18000
```

Comment: Have you found an answer?